# How to use p6spy with proxydatasource

Tags: java

Can anyone help me on how to use p6spy with proxyDatasource ?

As shown below, i have used the ProxyDataSource. So if i try to use the url as shown below, getting invalid url specified.

`oracle.url=jdbc:p6spy:oracle:thin:@HOSTNAME:1521:DBNAME`

Comment: Do configuration for p6spy library. take help from [p6spy.readthedocs.io](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) and from [mkyong.com](https://mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-display-hibernate-sql-parameter-values-solution/)

Comment: Done the configurations, since i am using proxydatasource, getting the invalid url error